# Problem with Keras to learn multiplication by two

Tags: keras, neural-network, deep-learning

I'm just trying to play around with Keras, but I'm running into some trouble trying to teach it a basic function (multiply by two). My setup is as follows. Since I'm new to this, I added in comments what I believe to be happening at each step.

```
x_train = np.linspace(1,1000,1000)
y_train=x_train*2
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32, input_dim=1, activation='sigmoid')) #add a 32-node layer
model.add(Dense(32, activation='sigmoid')) #add a second 32-node layer
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')) #add a final output layer
model.compile(loss='mse',
              optimizer='rmsprop') #compile it with loss being mean squared error

model.fit(x_train,y_train, epochs = 10, batch_size=100) #train 
score = model.evaluate(x_train,y_train,batch_size=100)
print(score)
```

I get the following output:

```
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s 355us/step - loss: 1334274.0375
Epoch 2/10
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s 21us/step - loss: 1333999.8250
Epoch 3/10
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s 29us/step - loss: 1333813.4062
Epoch 4/10
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s 28us/step - loss: 1333679.2625
Epoch 5/10
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s 27us/step - loss: 1333591.6750
Epoch 6/10
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s 51us/step - loss: 1333522.0000
Epoch 7/10
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s 23us/step - loss: 1333473.7000
Epoch 8/10
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s 24us/step - loss: 1333440.6000
Epoch 9/10
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s 29us/step - loss: 1333412.0250
Epoch 10/10
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s 21us/step - loss: 1333390.5000
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s 66us/step
['loss']
1333383.1143554687
```

It seems like the loss is extremely high for this basic function, and I'm confused why it's not able to learn it. Am I confused, or have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

- Using a sigmoid activation constrains your output to the range [0, 1]. But your target output is in the range [0, 2000], so your network cannot learn. Try a `relu` activation instead.
- Try using `adam` rather than `rmsprop` when debugging, it almost always works better.
- Train longer.

Putting it all together, I get the following output:

```
Epoch 860/1000
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s 29us/step - loss: 5.1868e-08
```